# How can I automatically detect if a colum is categorical?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I want to find a category of a pandas column. I can get the type but I'm struggling to figure out categories.

```
titanic_df = pd.read_csv('http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.csv')

#ID datatype

def idDataTypes(inputDataFrame):
    columnTypesDict = {} 
    import numpy as np
    import numbers
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
    from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

    for columns in inputDataFrame.columns.values:
        #print(columns)
        #try to convert to number. If it doesn't work it will convert to another type
        try:
            inputDataFrame[columns] = pd.to_numeric(inputDataFrame[columns], errors='ignore').apply(lambda x: x + 1 if isinstance(x, numbers.Number) else x) 
        except:
            print(columns, " cannot convert.")
        #print(inputDataFrame[columns].dtype)

        #create dictionary with the label
        if is_numeric_dtype(inputDataFrame[columns]): #products[columns].dtype == np.float64:
            columnTypesDict[columns] = "numeric"
        elif is_string_dtype(inputDataFrame[columns]): # products[columns].dtype == np.object:
            columnTypesDict[columns] = "string"
            #print(is_string_dtype(products[columns]))
        else:
            print("something else", prinputDataFrameoducts[columns].dtype)

    #category 
    cols = inputDataFrame.columns
    num_cols = inputDataFrame._get_numeric_data().columns
    #num_cols
    proposedCategory = list(set(cols) - set(num_cols))
    for value in proposedCategory:
        columnTypesDict[value] = "category"

    return(columnTypesDict)

idDataTypes(titanic_df)
```

The results I'm getting are not what I expect:

```
{'pclass': 'numeric',
 'survived': 'numeric',
 'name': 'category',
 'sex': 'category',
 'age': 'numeric',
 'sibsp': 'numeric',
 'parch': 'numeric',
 'ticket': 'category',
 'fare': 'numeric',
 'cabin': 'category',
 'embarked': 'category',
 'boat': 'category',
 'body': 'numeric',
 'home.dest': 'category'}
```

pclass should be a category and name should not be.

I'm not sure how to assess if something is a category or not. Any ideas?

Comment: why you need to do this while you can just do `titanic_df.info()` ?

Comment: I think for id'ing the data type i'm good. I think the challenge is if it's a category or not.  the results of .info() just shows the data type not category

Comment: I don't understand why you assume any string column is candidate to a category type while number are not? Is your goal to predict whether a variable is elligible to be a category? (if so, what are you defining as elligible, the number of distinct values for a given column less than some upper bound?)

Comment: @grodzi totally agree. It is the wrong assumption. I'm not sure how identify the categories either way. I thought of having it as a % of unique results vs number of items, but didn't have much success.

Comment: I can't help you much but I think this is a lost cause. You can consider any field as a categorical type, then study the relation between that field and the rest, whether there is correlation or not (for instance). To me you define a category _because_ you want to exhibit some properties. Now say you have another field which is the result of head or tail, you can make it a category. If I don't want to study whether head comes out more than tail, if don't want to link head to some combination of the other fields (I just don't give a damn about head or tail), then that category is useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the bug in your code:

```
proposedCategory = list(set(cols) - set(num_cols))
```

Everything other than the numeric columns are to become categories.

---

There is no right way to do this either, since whether a column is categorical is best decided manually with knowledge of the data the column contains. You are trying to do it automatically. One way to do it is to count the number of unique values in the column. It there are relatively few unique values, the column is likely categorical.

```
#category 
for name, column in inputDataFrame.iteritems():
    unique_count = column.unique().shape[0]
    total_count = column.shape[0]
    if unique_count / total_count < 0.05:
        columnTypesDict[name] = 'category'
```

The 5% threshold is random. No column will be identified as categorical if there are fewer than 20 rows in your dataframe. For best result, you will have to adjust that ratio of small and big dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

One quick (and lazy) workaround I've found out is using the Pandas .corr() method to automatically slash out numerical columns for you. As per my observation, .corr() automatically selects numerical columns when it returns the pairwise correlations for the entire dataframe. (Provided you have applied it on the entire dataset). Hence you can always linear search for the categorical columns in your original dataframe, if its not in the dataframe returned by .corr(). This might not be 100% effective but it does the job most of the time.

```
corr_df = df.corr() #returns a dataframe
num_cols = corr_df.columns
cat_cols = [cols for cols in df.columns if not cols in num_cols]
```

PS : Might be a bit time/memory intensive if dataset contains a lot of columns.